# Reducing a NSNumber by itself-1, automatically

Tags: ios, sleep, void, nsnumber, viewdidload

Ok so basically, I'm trying to build some code that allows an NSNumber to reduce by 1 every minute,

This is what I have so far.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSNumber *numVar = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:99];
[self num];
}
-(void)num{
usleep(60000000);
NSNumber *numVar = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:numVar-1];
[self num];
}
```

First off, it won't reduce by one every minute and secondly is it wrong to have the initial `numVar` in `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tried this and it worked fine for what we needed : 
You need to re-arrange this in your code though

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
     NSTimer *timer;
     int minutes = 0;

     //Creating a label that shows the timer ; i assume you have one that is already linked
     _labelTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is %i minute", minutes];

     //Creating the timer itself with the NSTimer object
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 60.0 target: self selector:@selector(decreaseTimeCount) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  

     //Note that 60 is the number of seconds before it calls the selector. You can use 1 if you want it to change your timer/clock every second
}
- (void)decreaseTimeCount{

    //The method changes the value of my variable and updates the label. If i'm at the 10th minute, i could do something, like perform a segue.

    minute+=1;
    _labTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is %i minutes", minutes];

    if (minutes == 10){
        //do stuff 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You sleep inside the main thread, blocking your UI. You need to use an NSTimer or similar timing mechanism to run the function periodically without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation YourViewController 
{
    NSNumber *numVar;
}    

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    numVar = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:99];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    numVar = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[numVar intValue] - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need something fast I do it like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(num) withObject:nil afterDelay:60];
}

- (void)num
{
    NSNumber *numVar = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:numVar-1];
    [self performSelector:@selector(num) withObject:nil afterDelay:60];
}
```

And you can decide in the num function wheather you want to do it again after a minute or not.